# Ck Editor not showing the youtube

Tags: ckeditor

I have build website and added the Ckeditor, 
in HTml mode i added the follwoing code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/pe3DH-_uapU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but its shwoing empty box in all browser

Comment: I vaguely remember CK filtering it, just try a Youtube plugin: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ckeditoryoutube/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the New Version Of the CKEditor You Could ply The YouTube Video in the editor

i tried your  code and its working

Down load it from here

http://ckeditor.com/download

Comment: I have tried it on Ckeditor 4.3.1 still not working ? If you got any other solution please let me know, even Ckeditor youtube plugin also not working.